# Array deallocating after a void function call modifies the array. C++

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, memory-management, exc-bad-access

I just wanted some help understanding this concept. I have a custom hash map programming I built for a school assignment. I declare a dynamic int array of a given size (11), hash user-inputted keys, and assign those array indices to those keys. My `insert` function assigns an array index generated by my `hash` function to a key argument. My `rehash` function increases the size to double its' original size and then to the nearest prime number after that, then calls the `insert` function to each old key-value pair and puts it into the larger array.

My question is that, when I use my `insert` function in the `main` method, the array is modified just fine. However, when I use my `rehash` function, the array I thought should be resizing isn't. Checking the array contents in the debugger after the `rehash` function call, any index after 10 is just garbage deallocated memory, even though I'm modifying the original array to a new size of 23 unless I'm doing it wrong.

Any clarification would be greatly appreciated. Thanks so much for the help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

const double LOAD_FACTOR = .5;
int numElements = 0;
int SIZE = 11;

int hash(int key, int *array);
void insert(int key, int *keys);
void rehash(int *keys);
int findPrime(int num);
bool isPrime(int num);
void printTable(int *keys);

int main() 
{
    int inputAmount;
    std::cout << "Enter the number of elements: ";
    std::cin >> inputAmount;

    int *array = new int[SIZE];
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        array[i] = 0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < inputAmount; i++)
    {
        int key;
        std::cout << "Enter a key: ";
        std::cin >> key;
        
        insert(key, array);
        numElements++;
        //check if the current load factor is greater than the load factor threshold
        //if it is, call the rehash function
        if(numElements*1.0 / SIZE > LOAD_FACTOR)
        {
            rehash(array);
        }
    }

    printTable(array);
}

int hash(int key, int *array)
{
    int index = key % SIZE;
    int oldIndex = index;
    int i = 1;
    while(array[index] != 0)
    {
        index = (oldIndex + i*i) % SIZE;
        i++;
    }
    return index;
}

void insert(int key, int *keys)
{
    int index = hash(key, keys);
    keys[index] = key;
}

void rehash(int *keys)
{
    int newSize = findPrime(SIZE*2);
    int *newKeys = new int[newSize]();

    int oldSize = SIZE;
    SIZE = newSize;

    for(int i = 0; i < oldSize; i++)
    {
        if(keys[i] != 0)
        {
            insert(keys[i], newKeys);
        }
    }

    delete[] keys;
    keys = new int[SIZE]();


    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        keys[i] = newKeys[i];
    }

    //return keys;

}
//finds a prime number greater than the given number
int findPrime(int num)
{
    int prime = num + 1;
    while(!isPrime(prime))
    {
        prime++;
    }
    return prime;
}

//create a function that checks if a number is prime
bool isPrime(int num)
{
    for(int i = 2; i < num; i++)
    {
        if(num % i == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

//create a print table function that takes an array of keys and prints the table
void printTable(int *keys)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        if(keys[i] != 0)
        {
            std::cout << keys[i] << " ";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "_ ";
        }
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: If you want `rehash` to modify the array/pointer passed from outside, you need to accept the address of the pointer (i.e. `int **`. passing by ref can also work: `int *&`). Having said that - I suggest you look into `std::vector` which prefered in c++ over raw c arrays.

Comment: The concept is called pass by value, you want pass by reference

Comment: `keys = new int[SIZE]();` in `rehash()` should be `newSize`, and similarly in the following `for()`. Although, you should use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: Your problem is that the argument `keys` of `rehash()` is a pointer passed by VALUE.  So an assignment like `keys = <anything>` will not be visible to the caller (since `keys` is a COPY of the pointer passed by the caller). If you must do things this way, either pass the pointer by reference (`int *&keys` instead of `int *keys`) or pass a pointer to a pointer (`int **keys`) and modify all usages of `keys` in the function to use `*keys`.    Better yet, don't use raw pointers or operators `new`/`delete` at all - use a standard container like `std::vector<int>` instead (and pass it by reference).

Comment: Not related to your problem, but `isPrime()` has terrible performance; at least stop at `i * i < num`!

Comment: And finally, `hash()` uses `SIZE`, when it should be using the current size, and the hash function is just `(key + index_of_first_null_in_array * index_of_first_null_in_array) % SIZE`, which means that the hash value may vary between calls, which is not what a hash function should be doing!